# Making rows in a GTK TreeView unselectable

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I want to make select rows of a PyGTK Tree-view (coupled to a List Store) un-selectable and if possible,greyed out.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit hackish minimal code, but it will make it impossible to select the middle row ('B'). If you wish that the previous selection should be remembered it ought to be quite easy to just store which rows are selected at the end of the signal-callback and overwrite current selection if a bad row was selected.

As for the individual rows and making them grey, I'm not sure...but this example here seems to deal with it: http://coding.debuntu.org/python-gtk-treeview-rows-different-colors

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

def clicked(selection):

    global selection_signal

    liststores, listpaths = selection.get_selected_rows()
    for selected_row in xrange(len(listpaths)):
        #The 1 looks for the 'B' row
        if listpaths[selected_row][0] == 1:
            #Blocking the handler so that the reverting doesn't invoke a callback
            selection.handler_block(selection_signal)
            selection.unselect_path(listpaths[selected_row])
            selection.handler_unblock(selection_signal)


w = gtk.Window()
treemodel = gtk.ListStore(str)
for r in ('A', 'B', 'C'):
    treemodel.append([r])

treeview = gtk.TreeView(treemodel)
w.add(treeview)
tv_cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
tv_column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Header", tv_cell, text=0)
treeview.append_column(tv_column)
selection = treeview.get_selection()
selection_signal = selection.connect("changed", clicked)
selection.set_mode(gtk.SELECTION_MULTIPLE)
w.show_all()
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I'm not going to worry about greying the rows out; it is only for internal use and really doesn't need to be that idiot-proof.

Answer (score 5):

The right way to do this is by using [`gtk.TreeSelection.set_select_function`](http://pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreeselection.html#method-gtktreeselection--set-select-function). Regarding how to gray out rows, it's possible to make the renderers not sensitive for them (see `sensitive=1` in the example below).

An example below:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk


def main():
    """Display treeview with one row not selectable."""
    window = gtk.Window()
    store = gtk.ListStore(str, bool)
    for row in (('A', True), ('B', False), ('C', True)):
        store.append(row)

    treeview = gtk.TreeView(store)
    renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
    column = gtk.TreeViewColumn('Name', renderer, text=0, sensitive=1)
    treeview.append_column(column)
    window.add(treeview)

    selection = treeview.get_selection()
    selection.set_select_function(
        # Row selectable only if sensitive
        lambda path: store[path][1]
    )
    selection.set_mode(gtk.SELECTION_MULTIPLE)
    window.show_all()
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```