# GTK in C: Disabling Expander Widget on Treeview Parent Node

Tags: c, treeview, gtk

I have a Treeview built using GTK where I have several parent nodes, with the first two parents having several children. The third parent node has a checkbox and when that is active I would like it to collapse the second parent and disable the expander for it so that it's children are no longer visible and can not be accessed. I came across several other posts on Stack Overflow that mention something similar:

[Making rows in a GTK TreeView unselectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783444/making-rows-in-a-gtk-treeview-unselectable)

[Disable expanding of all top level nodes of a treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969452/disable-expanding-of-all-top-level-nodes-of-a-treeview)

The first uses `gtk_tree_selection_set_select_function ()` and the second uses `gtk_tree_model_filter_set_visible_func ()`. I tried both to no avail, but the second approach would work for me (it should make that parent node hidden, rather than deactivate the expander). I think I am overlooking something. When I activate the checkbox for Parent Three the print statement appears from inside `visible_func` but no visibility is affected by the filtered model. I think I am overlooking something in regards to the `visible_func` functionality, but I am not sure what. A minimal example is below:

```
// gcc -Wall -Wextra -o treeview treeview.c $(pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs) -rdynamic -lm
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int check1 = 0, check2 = 0, check3 = 0, check4 = 0, check5 = 0, check6 = 0, check7 = 0;
double scale1 = 1.0, scale2 = 1.0, scale3 = 1.0, scale4 = 1.0, scale5 = 1.0, scale6 = 1.0, scale7 = 1.0;

GtkTreeView *treeview;
GtkWidget *view;

bool second_parent_access = true;

// These are the columns in the TreeView, enum is used to easily step through iter (i.e. parent -> child)
enum
{
  BUTTON_VIS = 0,
  BOLDNESS = 1,
  BUTTON = 2,
  CURRENT = 3,
  SCALE_VIS = 4,
  SCALE = 5,
  LABEL = 6,
  NUM_COLS = 7
};

// Event Handler for GtkCellRendererToggle being toggled
void on_cellrenderertoggle_toggled(__attribute__((unused)) GtkCellRendererToggle *cell_renderer, gchar *path, __attribute__((unused)) gpointer user_data)
{
  gboolean value;
  gboolean active;
  GtkTreeModel *model;
  GtkTreeIter iter;
  GtkTreeView *treeview;

  treeview = GTK_TREE_VIEW(view);

  // Toggle the cell renderer's current state to the logical not
  model = gtk_tree_view_get_model(treeview);

  if (gtk_tree_model_get_iter_from_string(model, &iter, path))
  {
    // Get the current state of the toggle button
    gtk_tree_model_get(model, &iter, BUTTON, &value, -1);
    // Set the state of the toggle button to the opposite of what it was
    gtk_tree_store_set(GTK_TREE_STORE(model), &iter, BUTTON, !value, -1);    
  }

  active = !value;

  // The form of the path is <parent>:<child> so for example we would have 3:4. We use the token ":" as 
  // the delimiter and split the string then convert from ASCII to integer.
  gchar **split_result = g_strsplit(path, ":", 0); // split_result[0] = parent, split_result[1] = child
  gint parent = g_ascii_strtoll(split_result[0], NULL, 10);
  g_strfreev(split_result);

  if (parent == 2) {
    if (active) {
      const gchar *path = "1";
      GtkTreePath *second_parent_path = gtk_tree_path_new_from_string (path);
      gboolean expanded;

      // Find out if Second Parent is expanded, if so collapse it
      expanded = gtk_tree_view_row_expanded(treeview, second_parent_path);

      if (expanded == TRUE)
        gtk_tree_view_collapse_row(treeview, second_parent_path);

      second_parent_access = false;
    }
    else 
      second_parent_access = true;
  }
}

// This event handler applies the changed text to the GtkCellRendererSpin cell in the TreeView.
static void scale_cell_edited(GtkCellRendererText *renderer, gchar *path, gchar *new_text, __attribute__((unused)) gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkTreeIter iter;
  GtkTreeModel *model;
  GtkAdjustment *adjustment;
  gdouble value;

  // Retrieve the current value stored by the spin button renderer's adjustment
  g_object_get(renderer, "adjustment", &adjustment, NULL);
  value = gtk_adjustment_get_value(adjustment);

  model = gtk_tree_view_get_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view));

  // It is the responsibility of the application to update the model and store new_text at the position indicated by path
  // This is a string and needs to be converted to a double
  value = atof(new_text);

  if(gtk_tree_model_get_iter_from_string(model, &iter, path))
  {
    gtk_tree_store_set(GTK_TREE_STORE(model), &iter, SCALE, value, -1);
  }
}

// This function creates and returns the GtkTreeModel (which is the interface needed by the GtkTreeStore)
GtkTreeModel *create_and_fill_model(void)
{
  GtkTreeStore *treestore;
  GtkTreeIter toplevel, child;

  // Creates a new tree store with NUM_COLS columns each of the types passed in
  treestore = gtk_tree_store_new(NUM_COLS, G_TYPE_BOOLEAN, G_TYPE_INT, G_TYPE_BOOLEAN,
                                 G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_BOOLEAN, G_TYPE_FLOAT, G_TYPE_INT);

  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &toplevel, NULL);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &toplevel, BUTTON_VIS, FALSE, BOLDNESS, 500, CURRENT,
                     "First Parent", SCALE_VIS, FALSE, LABEL, 1, -1);


  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &child, &toplevel);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &child, BUTTON_VIS, TRUE, BUTTON, check1, CURRENT,
                     "First Child", SCALE_VIS, TRUE, SCALE, scale1, LABEL, 2, -1);

  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &child, &toplevel);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &child, BUTTON_VIS, TRUE, BUTTON, check2, CURRENT,
                     "Second Child", SCALE_VIS, TRUE, SCALE, scale2, LABEL, 3, -1);

  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &child, &toplevel);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &child, BUTTON_VIS, TRUE, BUTTON, check3, CURRENT,
                     "Third Child", SCALE_VIS, TRUE, SCALE, scale3, LABEL, 4, -1);

  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &toplevel, NULL);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &toplevel, BUTTON_VIS, FALSE, BOLDNESS, 500, CURRENT,
                     "Second Parent", SCALE_VIS, FALSE, LABEL, 5, -1);

  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &child, &toplevel);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &child, BUTTON_VIS, TRUE, BUTTON, check4, CURRENT,
                     "First Child", SCALE_VIS, TRUE, SCALE, scale4, LABEL, 6, -1);

  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &child, &toplevel);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &child, BUTTON_VIS, TRUE, BUTTON, check5, CURRENT,
                     "Second Child", SCALE_VIS, TRUE, SCALE, scale5, LABEL, 7, -1);

  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &child, &toplevel);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &child, BUTTON_VIS, TRUE, BUTTON, check6, CURRENT,
                     "Third Child", SCALE_VIS, TRUE, SCALE, scale6, LABEL, 8, -1);

  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &toplevel, NULL);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &toplevel, BUTTON_VIS, TRUE, BUTTON, check7, BOLDNESS, 500, CURRENT,
                     "Third Parent", SCALE_VIS, TRUE, SCALE, scale7, LABEL, 9, -1);

  return GTK_TREE_MODEL(treestore);
}

// This function creates the container for the GtkTreeModel (interface) and the GtkTreeStore (data store)
GtkWidget *create_view_and_model()
{
  //GtkWidget *view;
  GtkTreeModel *model;

  view = gtk_tree_view_new();

  // COLUMN ONE POINTERS
  // Nothing to be rendered

  // COLUMN TWO POINTERS
  // Nothing to be rendered

  // COLUMN THREE POINTERS
  GtkTreeViewColumn *column3;
  GtkCellRenderer *check_box;
  check_box = gtk_cell_renderer_toggle_new();

  // COLUMN FOUR POINTERS
  GtkTreeViewColumn *column4;
  GtkCellRenderer *text;
  text = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

  // COLUMN FIVE POINTERS
  // Nothing to be rendered

  // COLUMN SIX POINTERS
  GtkTreeViewColumn *column6;
  GtkCellRenderer *mag_spin;
  mag_spin = gtk_cell_renderer_spin_new();
  GtkAdjustment * mag_adj;

  // COLUMN SEVEN POINTERS
  // Nothing to be rendered

  // *********COLUMN ONE*********
  // This stores a boolean value for visibility of Column THREE - there are no contents to be rendered

  // *********COLUMN TWO*********
  // This stores an integer value for font weight (i.e. "boldness" of text) of Column FOUR - nothing to render

  // *********COLUMN THREE*********
  // This is the checkbox column
  column3 = gtk_tree_view_column_new();

  // Set column title
  gtk_tree_view_column_set_title(column3, "");

  // Set fixed width for the column
  gtk_tree_view_column_set_fixed_width(column3, 50);

  // Pack tree view column into tree view
  gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view), column3);

  // Pack cell renderer into tree view column
  gtk_tree_view_column_pack_start(column3, check_box, TRUE);

  // Add the check box property to the column
  gtk_tree_view_column_add_attribute(column3, check_box, "active", BUTTON);

  // Add the visibility attribute to the column
  gtk_tree_view_column_add_attribute(column3, check_box, "visible", BUTTON_VIS);

  // Connect the signal for clicking the checkboxes in the treeview
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(check_box), "toggled", G_CALLBACK(on_cellrenderertoggle_toggled), NULL);

  // *********COLUMN FOUR*********
  // This is a string column listing the names for channel/current
  column4 = gtk_tree_view_column_new();

  // Set Column Title
  gtk_tree_view_column_set_title(column4, "Label");

  // Pack tree view column into tree view
  gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view), column4);

  // Pack cell renderer into tree view column
  gtk_tree_view_column_pack_start(column4, text, TRUE);

  // Set the properties on the cell renderer for adjusting boldness
  g_object_set(text, "weight-set", TRUE, NULL);

  // Add the boldness property to the column
  gtk_tree_view_column_add_attribute(column4, text, "weight", BOLDNESS);

  // Add the text property to the column
  gtk_tree_view_column_add_attribute(column4, text, "text", CURRENT);

  // *********COLUMN FIVE*********
  // This stores a boolean value for visibility of Column SIX - there are no contents to be rendered

  // *********COLUMN SIX*********
  // This is a GtkSpinButton column for adjusting the magnification of each current

  // Sets the GtkAdjustment for the scale
  // Arguments are initial value, min value, max value, step increment, page increment, and page size
  mag_adj = GTK_ADJUSTMENT(gtk_adjustment_new(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0));

  // Set the properties on the cell renderer for adjusting values
  g_object_set(mag_spin, "editable", TRUE, "adjustment", mag_adj, "digits", 3, NULL);

  // Connect the signal to the event handler that applies the changed text to the GtkCellRendererSpin cell
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(mag_spin), "edited", G_CALLBACK(scale_cell_edited), NULL);

  // Create the column and add the attributes
  column6 = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Spin Button", mag_spin, "text", SCALE, NULL);

  // Pack tree view column into tree view
  gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view), column6);

  // Add the visibility attribute to the column
  gtk_tree_view_column_add_attribute(column6, mag_spin, "visible", SCALE_VIS);

  // *********COLUMN SEVEN*********
  // This stores an integer to label the row for when it needs to be referenced upon
  // clicking to show the correct page in the GtkStack.

  // *********CREATE THE TreeModel*********

  // Hide the column header
  gtk_tree_view_set_headers_visible(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view), TRUE);

  // Connect the model created above
  model = create_and_fill_model();
  gtk_tree_view_set_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view), model);
  g_object_unref(model);

  return view;
}

// This function allows Second Parent to become invisible when the user checks Third Parent's checkbox
static gboolean visible_func (GtkTreeModel *model, GtkTreeIter *iter, __attribute__((unused)) gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkTreePath *path;
  path = gtk_tree_model_get_path (model, iter);
  gchar *path_string = NULL;
  path_string = gtk_tree_path_to_string(path);
  gboolean visible = TRUE;

  if (g_strcmp0(path_string, "2") == 0 && second_parent_access) {

    g_print("Turning visibility of Second Parent off.\n");
    visible = FALSE;
  }

  return visible;
}

static void destroy(__attribute__((unused)) GtkWidget *widget, __attribute__((unused)) gpointer user_data)
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // Initialize Gtk - used in lieu of GtkApplication
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  GtkWidget *window;
  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  // Link the GtkWidget containing the GtkTreeView to the Window container
  view = create_view_and_model();
  treeview = GTK_TREE_VIEW(view);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), view);

  GtkTreeModel *tree_model;
  GtkTreeModel *filtered_model;

  tree_model = gtk_tree_view_get_model(treeview);
  filtered_model = gtk_tree_model_filter_new (GTK_TREE_MODEL (tree_model), NULL);
  gtk_tree_model_filter_set_visible_func (GTK_TREE_MODEL_FILTER (filtered_model), visible_func, NULL, NULL);
  gtk_tree_view_set_model(treeview, gtk_tree_model_filter_get_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL_FILTER(filtered_model)));

  g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);

  // Show Main Window Widget
  gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(window));

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but wouldn't you just remove the children?

Comment: So are you thinking that I should have two separate treeviews, one with and without the children, and then rebuild each time? The thing is, this route seems extremely cumbersome for the small detail of just deactivating an inherent expander widget. At first I thought I could just make it insensitive but there doesn't seem to be anything in the API to do that...

Comment: The expander only shows when the parent has children. Remove the children, and the expander goes away, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion of theGtknerd, the solution I used is having two separate models, one with and without the children. I would like to think that there is a cleaner solution than this, but it does do the trick. Inside the `on_cellrenderertoggle_toggled` callback I set:

```
  if (parent == 2) {
    if (active) {
      check7 = 1;

      model = create_and_fill_filtered_model();
      gtk_tree_view_set_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view), model);

      g_print("ACTIVE\n");
    }
    else {
      check7 = 0;

      model = create_and_fill_model();
      gtk_tree_view_set_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view), model);

      g_print("INACTIVE\n");
    }
  }
```

and then I have another model with the children of Second Parent removed. This is defined as:

```
GtkTreeModel *create_and_fill_filtered_model(void)
{
  GtkTreeStore *treestore;
  GtkTreeIter toplevel, child;

  // Creates a new tree store with NUM_COLS columns each of the types passed in
  treestore = gtk_tree_store_new(NUM_COLS, G_TYPE_BOOLEAN, G_TYPE_INT, G_TYPE_BOOLEAN,
                                 G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_BOOLEAN, G_TYPE_FLOAT, G_TYPE_INT);

  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &toplevel, NULL);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &toplevel, BUTTON_VIS, FALSE, BOLDNESS, 500, CURRENT,
                     "First Parent", SCALE_VIS, FALSE, LABEL, 1, -1);


  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &child, &toplevel);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &child, BUTTON_VIS, TRUE, BUTTON, check1, CURRENT,
                     "First Child", SCALE_VIS, TRUE, SCALE, scale1, LABEL, 2, -1);

  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &child, &toplevel);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &child, BUTTON_VIS, TRUE, BUTTON, check2, CURRENT,
                     "Second Child", SCALE_VIS, TRUE, SCALE, scale2, LABEL, 3, -1);

  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &child, &toplevel);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &child, BUTTON_VIS, TRUE, BUTTON, check3, CURRENT,
                     "Third Child", SCALE_VIS, TRUE, SCALE, scale3, LABEL, 4, -1);

  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &toplevel, NULL);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &toplevel, BUTTON_VIS, FALSE, BOLDNESS, 500, CURRENT,
                     "Second Parent", SCALE_VIS, FALSE, LABEL, 5, -1);

  gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &toplevel, NULL);
  gtk_tree_store_set(treestore, &toplevel, BUTTON_VIS, TRUE, BUTTON, check7, BOLDNESS, 500, CURRENT,
                     "Third Parent", SCALE_VIS, TRUE, SCALE, scale7, LABEL, 6, -1);

  return GTK_TREE_MODEL(treestore);
}
```

Note that the global `second_parent_access` boolean flag is no longer needed, since all parent menus collapse when the tree is rebuilt. This then has the desired functionality.